# Why my manufacturer splash screen is not showing?

Tags: fedora, boot, display

I recently installed Fedora 22 on a dual-boot with Windows 8 on the other. But, since I installed it, I have had the following problem:

When I press my power button to switch it on, the screen just shows black (or navy blue) for some seconds, goes off and then show a dimmer version of the color basically till I switch the system off.

It won't work again until I restart a couple of times (2-20). I receive an error once I boot into Fedora:

```
Error:BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.0.7 crashed.
```

Comment: It's probably related either to your installing the wrong Fedora *(MBR and not GPT/UEFI)* or it is a question better asked your manufacturer. 10:1, though, they'll want more information than this. Definitely I do.

Comment: It happened again and this time I discovered that I could log into my Fedora and `poweroff` from terminal, but nothing was showing on the screen, better still the screen was grey till it powered off. Is there any chance the BIOS doesn't recognize the screen cause I expect the BIOS to be aware of the screen before grub. I will also check whether my system is **UEFI** or **MBR**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved, It was actually a screen problem(although I still don't understand how shutting down causes it to be more persistent). The connector at the back of the screen us shaky